# electron-rebuild "Unable to find Electron app ..."

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

After installing a native module via npm for use with Electron (atom shell) I'm trying to run electron-rebuild:

```
>>./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
```

from the project directory,b "~/project_js/React-Redux-Py-Electron/" (which *contains* node_modules/). But I receive this error message:

```
>>Unable to find Electron app at ~/project_js/React-Redux-Py-Electron/console.log(process.versions.modules)
```

Using versions:

```
node v6.2.0, 
npm 3.8.9, 
electron-prebuilt 1.2.0, 
electron-rebuild 1.1.4,
```

which I believe are all the latest.  At one time, perhaps before some version upgrades, this worked.

Can anyone explain and suggest a fix?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm getting the same error but from https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate . Thanks.

Comment: No I didn't.  I ended up using the less convenient rebuild method. As much as I like Electron, stuff like this makes me think it's still a bit "rough around the edges".

Comment: `npm run build && npm start` fixed it for me

Answer (score 99):

Check if your package.json has "main" key.
Here main.js is your Electron Configuration JS file.

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "main.js"
}
```

Answer (score 16):

The entry point file name and `package.json` main file name should be same. Consider your entry point file name is `app.js` then `package.json` looks like

```
{
  "name": "myelectron",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For me it was throwing this error because of missing `package.json` file in the folder I was running `electron` command. Make sure the folder consists of files named

1. `main.js`
2. `index.html`
3. `package.json`

and define variables `electron`,  `app` and `BrowserWindow` in `main.js` are as

```
               const electron = require('electron');             
               const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;
```

Comment: Solved the issue :)

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you defined entry point for the application. generally, it's always a `index.js` or `main.js`. You need to specify in `package.json` as an entry point of application. In this case what happened is, electron need the entry point and it didn't find from `package.json` and unable to start the `main process`. To fix it up, You can add `main` property as root property in package.json as given below,

```
{
  "name": "YOUR_APP_NAME",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js"
}
```

Another important thing is, just check once the dependencies by running command `npm list --depth=0` and confirm that `electron` is there.

Answer (score 5):

for me the issue was caused due to inconsistency with the name when running the `Electron` command.

Ensure that the filename provided for run should be the same as the one provided in the **main** entry in package.json e.g. on Mac OS
`/Applications/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron hello-world` matches with the `hello-world.js` in **main** package.json

```
{
  "name": "first_electron_app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "hello-world.js",
  "dependencies": {    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`npm run build && npm start` fixed it for me

Comment: Both commands depend on what they are configured for in `package.json` / `scripts`, so this information is of no use without the contents of `package.json`

Comment: it did fix for me.